# Page can't be found error and not hitting my app while url contains like .vpf,.html (dot extensions)

Tags: asp.net-core

If I am using an url like '**' it goes to the error page. But, my application is not getting hit while giving url like '.vpf' or '.vd'. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added route with constraints in startup.cs

```
     routes.MapRoute(

           name: "xxx",

           template: "{xx}/{yy}/{*zz}",

           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },

           constraints: new { xx= @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", yy= @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", zz= @"(.*?)\.(vpf)" }

           );
```

Its working for .vpf

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for your web server? IIS?

You need to add Handler Mappings for those file types that you want to serve; note that IIS will have defaults for .htm, .axd, etc, but not other types, like .vpf.

Try requesting those files directly in the browser (not via javascript) and running Fiddler at the same time, and you should get more information about what is and isn't happening.

Comment: Thanks,I am getting this error  in localhost also.can i mention defaults of  web.config as .vpf or anything